# iterating over a javascript list and process specific objects

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I have a collection (list) of objects like below,

```
books{
 book1[
   isSelected = false;
   /*other properties*/
 ],

 book2[
   isSelected = true;
   /*other properties*/
 ],

  book3[
   isSelected = false;
   /*other properties*/
 ]
}
```

I want to iterate over this list and print ALL the objects which are having property `isSelected` as `true` followed by ALL the objects having property `isSelected` as `false`.

Please guide me on this approach.

Answer (score 2):

A simple solution in vanilla JS is to sort the array by the property:

```
books.sort(function(a, b) {
    return b.isSelected - a.isSelected
})
```

An underscore way would be [`groupBy`](http://underscorejs.org/#groupBy):

```
r = _.groupBy(books, 'isSelected')
console.log(r[true]);
console.log(r[false]);
```